# left coset of Kernel and Image relationship.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

if we have Groups G, and H, and homomorphism F between them
and left cosets g*Ker(F)

Why is it that **"there is one left coset [g*Ker(F)] for each element of Im(F)"**

(This is part of the answer to part (ii) of the attached question).

[Image of full question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL2oj.png)
Thanks!

Comment: You want to prove that $F(x)=F(y)$ if and only if the coset containing $x$ equals the coset containing $y$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Where F(x) is the image of a particular element of G? is this essentially what the first pat of the question proves (question in the link)? And thanks!

Comment: $F$ has domain $G$, so $F(x)$ must mean the image of the element $x$ of $G$ under $F$. I haven't looked at the link.

Comment: @GerryMyerson okay fantastic that was my understanding. If you get time to look at it, that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun thank you I have been doing this on all my future posts now. I was concerned about making them overly lengthy, but I see now people appreciate the detail and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $S_{h'}=S_h\iff h'=h$, and, by (i), $S_h$ is a left coset of the kernel of $\phi$. (Symbols are as in the linked excerpt.)